# how to create a dialog in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know javascript, but I have to do my homework. Please help me to add a dialog box to an HTML table! I found some example patterns for the javascript, but I don't know how to make those work with HTMLtables.

This is how my HTML code should look like, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button">Show Confirmation Box</button>
        <dialog class="mdl-dialog">
          <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Confirm</h4>
          <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
            <p> blah blah blah </p>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </dialog>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button">Show Confirmation Box</button>
        <dialog class="mdl-dialog">
          <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Confirm</h4>
          <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
            <p> blah blah blah  </p>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </dialog>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and that is what I found about dialogs. I had an idea to make querySelectorAll and then to perform it all in a loop, but it didn't work correctly. I'm praying for help!

```
<script>
    var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
    var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.showModal();
    });
    dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you want to add showDialog listener on multiple buttons?

Comment: @jaysurya sorry! the second part of the code should work correctly for each line with a button in a table! so how to add this event handler to all buttons...

Comment: using `querySelector('#show-dialog')` will match only the first element. so you should assign class instead of id and use `getElementsByClassName('show-dialog')`. in js, you need to use a for loop in order to show  dialog box to their respective button clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem must be because of the selector here. `id` selector must be unique throughout your html. If you want to access multiple items you must use `class` attribute(or custom data-* attributes). So, add a class attribute to the buttons.
Change your code to,

**html**

```
...
<button id="show-dialog-btn1" type="button" class="mdl-button show-dialog">Show Confirmation Box</button>
...
<button id="show-dialog-btn2" type="button" class="mdl-button show-dialog">Show Confirmation Box</button>
...
<script>
    var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
    var showDialogButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.show-dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i< showDialogButtons.length;i++){
      showDialogButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        dialog.showModal();
      });
    }
    dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  </script>
```

And make sure you assign different `id` value to each button.